# MySQL Fulltext Query: How to Speed Up The Following Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which is taking 10 seconds to execute on a server with ram of 32gb and a pretty fast processor and an ssd

product_name has a fulltext index, product_description has a fulltext index, and there is a fulltext index on both product_name & product_description combined

If i don't use boolean mode, i am able to get the results fast but the required relevancy is missing

```
SET SESSION query_cache_type=0;
SELECT 
    p.sku,
    p.product_name,
    p.product_description,
    ( MATCH (p.product_name) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2 +word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 10 ) AS score1,
    ( MATCH (p.product_description) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2 +word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 20 ) AS score2,
    ( MATCH (p.product_name,p.product_description) AGAINST ('word1,word2,word3') * 30 ) AS score3 
FROM products AS p 
WHERE 
    ( 
        ( MATCH (p.product_name) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2 +word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 10 ) > 0 OR 
        ( MATCH (p.product_description) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2 +word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 20 ) > 0 OR 
        ( MATCH (p.product_name,p.product_description) AGAINST ('word1,word2,word3') * 30 ) 
    ) AND 
    p.sku NOT LIKE '4%' 
ORDER BY score1 DESC,score2 DESC,score3 DESC LIMIT 0,15
```

Explain shows "Using where; Using filesort" that means query is not using the fulltext indexes

How do i speed up the query? Or how to troubleshoot the problem further?

OUTPUT OF EXPLAIN:
[image]

OUTPUT OF SHOW INDEX:
[image]

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: What do you mean by "word1,word2,word3"? You might want to use just one `match against` in `where` (it looks to me as if the last one wshould include the other 2 anyway, but i'm not so sure what you actually want to express there) and then rank this by the specific results in the select clause. 3 fulltext searches will need more time than 1. And please add `show index` and `explain`

Comment: I have added output of explain

Comment: @Solarflare 

i need the most relevant matches first (which are containing all three words, i.e, word1 and word2, and word3) 

and then i need the matches containing word1 and word2, word2 and word3, word1 and word3 

and then i need the matches containing word1 or word2 or word3 in the last place

Comment: What you are doing is: looking for: "word1 and word2 and word3" in table1, looking for "word1 and word2 and word3" in table 2, then for "word1 or word2 or word3" in them table1+2. If "word1 and word2 and word3" is true, the 3rd query "word1 or word2 or word3" would have included that too already, so you are doing 3 full text searches, but 2 of them can't add anything to the result of the third. So do just the 3rd search in the `where` and use the ranks in your select to do the sorting.

Comment: Could you please explain how to do that? i want to show record having all three words first, then any of the two words next, and then any one word next. Doing just the third query is missing the relevance.

Comment: You are not calculating the relevance in where, you are selecting in where. Just remove the 2 lines `( MATCH (p.product_name) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2 +word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 10 ) > 0 OR 
        ( MATCH (p.product_description) AGAINST ('+word1 +word2 +word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 20 ) > 0 OR ` from your where and test it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113177/discussion-between-brucekaushik-and-solarflare).

Comment: @Solarflare: Excellent! it really did help, i did get the syntax wrong! The query has indeed executed really fast! Thanks a lot buddy :)